# ODBC Driver "Oracle in OraClient11g_home1" required but can't seem to get it on Windows 10

Tags: odbc

Not sure if this was the right StackExchange for this. My job recently upgraded their machines to Windows 10 and I thought setting them up would be a breeze, but I can't for the love of me figure out how to get the correct ODBC drivers on it. I've tried every download I could find and it isn't giving me the right driver.

[image: Drivers list]

Not sure where to get the drivers I need. I thought it'd be simple but I just can't find it anywhere after hours of searching. I don't know enough about database connections to know if I can just utilize one of these drivers and somehow translate the configuration from before onto them (old driver just had main entries for Data Source Name, Description, TNS Service Name, and User ID - that's all I enter to make the connection work.)

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. I was looking in the 32bit drivers without realizing. But the problem I have now is that it's a 64bit driver and the Excel sheet that utilizes the connection is looking for the 32bit one.